# How to generate a legacy-compatible address using Ledger Live?

Tags: segregated-witness, address-generation, ledger-hardware-wallet

I'm trying to withdraw funds from Bittrex to my Ledger device, but it seems they do not accept native Segwit addresses.

Is it possible to generate a legacy-compatible address (for instance a P2SH-wrapped segwit address starting with `3...`) using Ledger Live?

Comment: I assume you are using Ledger Live to generate the address?

Comment: I've significantly edited your post to make it clearer. Please feel free to revert the edit if i missed something.

Comment: Thank you for making it extra clear however i don't know if Bittrex  likes the wrapped segwit P2SH  or only  the P2PKH starting with 1

Comment: According to https://www.reddit.com/r/Bittrex/comments/my5zzl/depositing_to_bittrex_from_native_segwitbech32/, they support P2PKH and P2SH.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on that